# Mootools Response in variable

Tags: ajax, mootools, response

I tryed tu put the ajax response in a variable tu use it later but it's not work

this is my code

```
var retourn;    

var requestData = new Request ({
    url: 'dnscheck.php',
    async:false,
    onComplete: function(response){
        //alert(response); // this work good
        retourn = response;
    }
});

alert(retourn); // shows me undefined
```

mootools 1.2.4 version

Any idea how to resolve this plaise

---

After clearing history and trying many time, it work fine thank you Grim

```
var retourn;    

var requestData = new Request ({
    url: 'dnscheck.php',
    async:false,
    onComplete: function(response){
        //alert(response); // this work good
        retourn = response;
    }
});

requestData.send();
alert(retourn); // work fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that ajax calls are asynchronous, so the code in your *onComplete* handler will only be executed when the call returns, while instead your final alert will be executed immediately  after the code creating the request (which you must start by calling the *send* method, btw) - at this time the variable will always be uninitialized.

**Edit**: didn't notice you used aync: false (which is usually a bad idea btw...) - you still need to *send* the request though

```
requestData.send();
```

**Edit(2):** Also, it is best not to use the onComplete callback (it is called when the response returns, even before checking *what* was actually returned) - instead use the onSuccess callback, and be aware that there are many reasons that the response may fail, so you might want to define the onFailure callback as well and do something in there too.

```
    var retourn;    

    var requestData = new Request ({
        url: 'yoururl.php',
        async:false,
        onSuccess: function(response){
            retourn = response;
        },
        onFailure: function(xhr) {
            retourn = "failed";
        }
    });

    requestData.send();

            alert(retourn);
```

Comment: thank's for your answer.

But, what i should doing to wait until i receive the response ? and put the result in variable and continue script execution ?

Because when i put the alert after **requestData.send()** it steel have the same error